# Get the event functions in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How could I get the event functions in `d3.js`?

For example, someone wrote the code:

```
var handleRelease = function() {
   console.log("hello world");
}
var foo = d3.select("#foo").on("mouseup", handleRelease);
```

Now I want to add my own function to be called when the `foo` gets released. How would I do that without breaking someone else code? I mean if I write:

```
var myFunction = function() {
   console.log("bye, bye");
}
foo.on("mouseup", myFunction);
```

The function `handleRelease` won`t be called now.

So, in order to avoid the `x-y` problem here I explained what I need the list of attached event functions for.

And search [results](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=d3.js+get+event+functions&oq=d3.js+get+event+functions&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j0l4.4617j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) did not help at all.

Comment: Does `foo.on("mouseup", function() { handleRelease(); myFunction(); });` not work?

Comment: Why not just add `console.log("bye, bye");` to the function `handleRelease`, or add `myFunction()` - then you're not overwriting, more extending

Comment: @Shashank, that is about code management. It does not matter whether or not it is working now, I want to keep my code clean.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney, it is about keeping the code clean.

Comment: This keeps it cleaner than adding more event handlers to do the same thing that a handler is already doing imho

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You nailed it with your assessment that this might be an XY-problem! For what you are trying to achieve you do not need the list of registered event handlers. D3 already provides means to assign multiple handlers to a single event type by allowing you to provide a custom name/namespace. The specification for [`selection.on()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_on) has it (emphasis mine):

> The type may be optionally followed by a period (`.`) and a name; the optional name **allows multiple callbacks to be registered to receive events of the same type**, such as `click.foo` and `click.bar`.

For your code this could be something like this:

```
var handleRelease = function() {
   console.log("hello world");
}
var foo = d3.select("#foo").on("mouseup.handleRelease", handleRelease);

var myFunction = function() {
   console.log("bye, bye");
}
foo.on("mouseup.myFunction", myFunction);
```

Both functions are then independently registered as handlers for the `mouseup` event and will not with one another.